# how do i know api is called securly via https or not

Tags: php, api

So we have created an api, we want to make sure it is called via https secure connection, how do we know from api it is serveing securely. For example if from another domain comes request to our api like this:

```
https://ourdomain.com/api.php?appId=dev4&apiKey=XXXX
```

From `api.php`, how do we know we are accessed securly via https ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an HTTPS request is handled by a PHP script, $_SERVER autoglobal is filled with many extra headers related to SSL. You can check some of these.

I would check `$_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on'`

```
[HTTPS] => on
[SSL_SERVER_S_DN_C] => IT
[SSL_SERVER_S_DN_ST] => Some-State
[SSL_SERVER_S_DN_L] => Italy
[SSL_SERVER_S_DN_O] => test
[SSL_SERVER_S_DN_OU] => test
[SSL_SERVER_S_DN_CN] => test
[SSL_SERVER_S_DN_Email] => test@example.com
[SSL_SERVER_I_DN_C] => IT
[SSL_SERVER_I_DN_ST] => Some-State
[SSL_SERVER_I_DN_L] => Country
[SSL_SERVER_I_DN_O] => test
[SSL_SERVER_I_DN_OU] => test
[SSL_SERVER_I_DN_CN] => test
[SSL_SERVER_I_DN_Email] => test@example.com
[SSL_VERSION_INTERFACE] => mod_ssl/2.2.24
[SSL_VERSION_LIBRARY] => OpenSSL/1.0.1e
[SSL_PROTOCOL] => TLSv1
[SSL_SECURE_RENEG] => true
[SSL_COMPRESS_METHOD] => NULL
[SSL_CIPHER] => DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
[SSL_CIPHER_EXPORT] => false
[SSL_CIPHER_USEKEYSIZE] => 256
[SSL_CIPHER_ALGKEYSIZE] => 256
[SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY] => NONE
[SSL_SERVER_M_VERSION] => 1
[SSL_SERVER_M_SERIAL] => C6D11EC56F9B9F1A
[SSL_SERVER_V_START] => Oct 31 09:51:34 2013 GMT
[SSL_SERVER_V_END] => Jul 27 09:51:34 2018 GMT
[SSL_SERVER_S_DN] => /C=IT/ST=Some-State/L=Italy/O=test/OU=test/CN=test/emailAddress=test@example.com
[SSL_SERVER_I_DN] => /C=IT/ST=Some-State/L=Italy/O=test/OU=test/CN=test/emailAddress=test@example.com
[SSL_SERVER_A_KEY] => rsaEncryption
[SSL_SERVER_A_SIG] => sha1WithRSAEncryption
[SSL_SESSION_ID] => 832D61116CB619ACF9B9FD3080B2BC8DB48343B3033023D683AC8A9D22C6A064
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i was looking for. will accept this answer as soon as it allows me.

Answer (score 1):

you can add this condition in `api.php` :

```
if (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'off') {
    // no ssl 
} else {
    // ssl
}
```

edit : as @*Salman A* said, the `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` could be 'on' or 'off'. So I've changed the code.

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` could contain the string `"off"` and `"off"` is not empty.

Comment: Still wrong. You check for empty and == off at the same time, will always be false.

Comment: @Ghigo, thx. corrected a bit too fast.